# A north country question: is Varmint the root of Warm 'un?

Tags: british-english, dialects, phrase-origin

I would like to examine the proposition that the Yorkshire and north country term **warm ‘un** may derive from the word **varmint**.

I was brought up in south Yorkshire and often heard children referred to as a *warm ‘un*. The phrase usually applied to lively, mischievous or otherwise exceptionally active children who entertained or irritated adults. “*Ee – ee’s a warm ‘un!*”

*Un* is not difficult:

> [Yorkshire Express](https://theyorkshirepress.co.uk/yorkshire/yorkshire-sayings-expressions-phrases-dictionary/)
> Un – one

*Warm* poses more interest. In my childlike naivety I assumed it meant “*A warm one*”, drawing some sort of parallel with a hot and active fire (of which there were many in a coalfield area).

Later I thought it to relate to the adult use of *hot*, referring to a sexually active and attractive person:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hot)
> Hot:
> sexually attractive, or feeling sexually excited:
> *She's really hot!
>
> I'm hot for you, baby.
>
> I've got a hot date tonight.*

Being slang, there are only limited quotations available. We have:

> [Milly Johnson](https://millyjohnson.co.uk/a-yorkshire-glossary/)
> Warm un:
> Witty
> bit of a slapper (female).
> *Elsie down the road is a warm un.*

> [Yorkshire Post](https://www.yorkshirepost.co.uk/heritage-and-retro/retro/i-was-saying-z-yorkshire-dialect-1941839)
> He’s a warm (rhymes with harm) un” (has a bob or two, nicely off)

> [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/northyorkshire/voices2005/glossary/glossary.shtml)
> Amt Tyke (a contributor to the BBC):
> Anyone know this one: “tha's a warm un”? {= “You are a warm one”}

while over the border in Lancashire is:

> [Lancashire Songs; Edwin Waugh](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Lancashire_Songs/9avEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22warm+%27+un%22&pg=PT43&printsec=frontcover)
> “*A needle would keep th' body wake, An' th' soul met still be dozin'; But this receipt would set it reet, Iv th' mixture wur a warm un — Yo'm get some stingin' gospel-snuff, An' put it into th' sarmon.*"

In summary, *warm* seems to be associated with childhood precocity and naughtiness, spiciness, wealth, sexual attraction and – more generally – with types of egregiousness.

However, more recently I have had the suspicion that some of these uses derive from a simple spoken corruption of **Varmint**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/varmint)
> a contemptible person : rascal broadly : person, fellow

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/varmint)
> an annoying child:
> *The little varmints stole my wallet!*

I add the aural aspect of this question: the pronunciation I knew - and it is exemplified by the Yorkshire Post quotation - was *Warm* rhyming with *Arm*.

Add to this the sort of sound shifts we see between Scando-German "warm" (initial "V" sound in German, Swedish and others), the Scandinavian-Viking influence in northern England, all contrasting with the usual English "warm" (initial "w" sound), and you may see the reasons for my notion.

Do you agree with this suspicion?

Comment: I don't see how you get from warm' un to varmint. The sounds are completely different....

Comment: And varmint is vermin.

Comment: @Lambie A good point when coming from the perspective of, say, southern England, so I have edited my question to cover it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Indeed yes, but that meaning is not directly relevant to my question.

Comment: “*Do you agree with this suspicion?* is not really a question, it is  more on the POB side.

Comment: ee’s a warn ‘un. Is that a typo in paragraph 2?

Comment: *varmint* from *vermin* and *verm* from ***worm***. Not *warm*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat the question unambiguously asks the origin of *warm ‘un*, and not about the origin of *vermin*, which is well known and accessible to etymological research.

Comment: @k1eran thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

*warm’un* reminds me of *wane/we’an/wean* widely used in Ulster/Scotland.

> **Weans**
> Derived from wee, meaning little, and ane meaning one, wean is a word most commonly used in the West of Scotland to refer to a young child, and is sometimes also spoken as wee yin or ‘little one’.
> [The Scotsman](https://www.scotsman.com/arts-and-culture/scottish-word-week-weans-and-bairns-1551291)

I think OP’s original idea re. *warm one* is a very promising avenue, and to my ears, it simply implies an *alive/lively/living/warm-blooded one* as opposed to *a dead/cold/cold-hearted one*.

Comment: I agree with your implied point about *wean* (*wain*, as I know it), = *wee 'un*", = *wee one* = *little one*. It illustrates well the use of *one* or *'un* that I refer to. In passing I note scope for another question that I will not ask yet - if at all: might *wean* derive from the verb *wean*?

Comment: @Anton where I live everyone knows the word wean/wain and use it in speech, but most (including me) are hazy on how to spell it 

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following entry, it seems *warm ’un* has nothing to do with varmints.

Under ***warm***, in [*Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present — A Dictionary, Historical and Comparative, of the Heterodox Speech of All Classes of Society for More Than Three Hundred Years. With Synonyms in English, French, German, Italian, Etc · Volume 7*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Slang_and_Its_Analogues_Past_and_Present/0JhBAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22warm+%27un%22&pg=PA294&printsec=frontcover) (1890) we find:

> WARM (= wanton) DESIRE: a WARM (= lecherous) MEMBER (or WARM-’UN): a
> harlot or whoremonger : *cf.* HOT-UN, SCHORCHER (*q.v.*);

And this quote:

> *c.* 1889. *Music Hall Song*, ‘Salvation Sarah.’ They call me Salvation Sarah, a warm-’un I have been; but now I am converted, I’ll
> never go wrong again.

You can find there other meanings for *warm* (albeit without *’un*) more suitable for children.

Here are some definitions of *warm* from the *OED*:

> **warm**, *adj.* and *n.<sup>2</sup>*
>
> **10. b.** Of the passions or disposition in general: Prone to excitement, ardent, impulsive; apt to disregard the voice of cool
> reason.
>
> **11.** Hot-tempered, angry.
>
> **13.** Characterized by, of the nature of, prone to, sexual desire; amorous.
>
> **14. b.** Of imaginative composition: Indelicate in its appeal to sexual emotion.
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

However you want to spin it, there’s no need to get varmints involved.

Comment: Well argued as to the meaning of *warm*, and elaborating nicely on my brief recognition of the sexually active overtones of the word, albeit not actually refuting that the varmint proposition may still lead to the same construction. Let us see what others have to say..